# "a comparison between A and B" or "a comparison of A and B"?

Tags: sentence-construction, comparison

When I have to compare two things A and B, can I say "a comparison between A and B" or "a comparison of A and B". Which is best ?

Answer (score 16):

To keep things super-duper simple:

**Both are fine. They mean *exactly* the same thing.**

Use either one. No one will misunderstand you. Both are equally common in everyday usage. In fact, if anything, I would say that "a comparison of A and B" is perhaps more common, even though it may sound slightly less correct. [This Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comparison+of%2C+comparison+between&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) would seem to back me up.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: As a side note, if you were to change "comparison" to "difference" (the difference between A and B, etc), then it would matter, and "of" would be wrong. They are similar phrases, so I thought I should point it out.

Comment: +1 You might add that 'with' and 'to' also work. Also, it might be judicious to add a link to the NGram, so users can see just what parameters you employed - and play around with them, as [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comparison+of%2Ccomparison+between%2Ccomparison+to%2C+comparison+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: Good point. I added links on the image and the "This Ngram" text.

Comment: I love the screaming headline.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare A with B, then the comparison is between A and B. You could also say "comparison of A with B" as in the following sentence.

> The immediacy of effect is assessed both with the observed data from phases 1 and 2, and a **comparison of** the observed data in phase 2 with the projected data from phase 1.

You could also say "comparison of A and B" as in the following sentence.

> Counseling smoking parents of young children: **comparison of** pediatricians and family physidans.

Answer (score 0):

You use *between* when you are comparing two things and *among* when comparing more than two things.

Ex.

> *Between* my brother and sister, my brother is easily the most spoiled.
>
> Tom is the smartest *among* my friends.

Comment: I don't see how your answer addresses the question asked. The poster seems to be interested in the correctness of the expressions indicated, not in the usage of *between* and *among*.